# Basic sequencing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, so bear with me...

I have an external JavaScript document linked to my HTML (called within the head of the HTML doc).

In my JavaScript doc, I call two functions on the `window.onload` event:

```
window.onload = function() {
    selected_state();
    viewer();
};

function selected_state() {
    var titleAr = document.getElementsByTagName("title");
    var aAr = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    // Take the first element of title array. Check if it matches
    // the first element of link array.
    for (i = 0; i <= titleAr.length; i++) {
        for (l = 0; l <= aAr.length; l++) {
            if (titleAr[i].innerHTML === aAr[l].innerHTML) {
                aAr[l].style.color = "#C33";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

function viewer() {
    var imgAr = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgAr.length; i++) {
        imgAr[i].onmouseover = function() {
            this.style.border = "1px solid #CCC";
        }
    }
};​
```

The first function runs without problems, but the second one doesn't run. If I switch them around, so `viewer()` is first, then `selected_state()` won't execute. I know the issue is probably something really simple logic wise... Any takers?

Comment: you've got error(s) in both the functions ?!

Comment: The first one works independently. So does the second. It's when they're combined the second in the sequence doesn't execute.

Comment: You know `l` and `i` are global... There's two `i` so that might be the problem right there

Comment: @elclanrs: *"There's two `i` so that might be the problem right there"* Only the `i` in `selected_state` is global (as is the `l`). The other (in `viewer`) is declared as a local.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, yeah but in the second function `imgAr[i]` is it using the global `i` or the local `i`? In any case OP needs to add some `var` there unless they're declared somewhere else, it's confusing and it might cause problems

Comment: @elclanrs: In the second function, `imgAr[i]` is using the local `i`. Yes, it's confusing, and yes the other ones should be declared, but there's no question which one `viewer` is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `selected_state` is breaking when the inner loop finishes in the outer loop's first run; your loop condition is incorrect *(must be throwing something like "index out of bounds")*.

Arrays use a *zero-based index*:

Change:

```
for (i=0; i <= titleAr.length; i++) {
    for (l=0; l <= aAr.length; l++) {
```

To:

```
for (i=0; i < titleAr.length; i++) {
    for (l=0; l < aAr.length; l++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation is that both functions throw exceptions after doing whatever it is that makes you think they've run without trouble. Barring their throwing exceptions, first the first one will run, then the second one will run. There's no basic logic error you're missing. But if the first function throws an exception, that transfers control out to the next exception catching frame, which (if you haven't defined one via `try...catch`) will be outside of your code.

Your best bet is to use a decent debugger to find out what's going on. All major browsers now have decent debuggers built in. In IE and Chrome, press F12 to open the debugger; in other browsers, look at the menus. The debugger will have a "console" where it reports errors. You can also set breakpoints and walk through the code statement-by-statement.

---

*(Edit now you've posted the code.)*

Note that your code in `selected_state` falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You need to declare `i` and `l` with `var`.

Comment: the javascript debugger returned this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: @user1481563 *Arrays use a zero-based index*